# PHP EBS - SecureHash validation failed

Tags: php, validation, payment-gateway, ebs-payment

I am trying to implement EBS payment getway.

i filled all mandatory inputs in form.

code

```
<?php
    $hash = "ebskey"."|".$_POST['account_id']."|".$_POST['amount']."|".$_POST['reference_no']."|".$_POST['return_url']."|".$_POST['mode'];

    $secure_hash = md5($hash);
?>

 <input name="secure_hash" type="hidden" size="60" value="<?php echo $secure_hash;?>" />
```

But i get below error.

```
Oops!
It seems an error has occured, the page you are trying to reach is not accessible.

Error!

SecureHash validation failed
```

what does error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: [PHP EBS Integration kit V 2.5](https://support.ebs.in/app/index.php?/default_import/Knowledgebase/Article/View/547/0/php-ebs-integration-kit-v-25)

**Possibilities of Errors:**
The error “Secure Hash validation failed” will occur if the below criteria are not satisfied:

- Ensure that this option “Secure Hash” has to be enabled on EBS
  merchant portal. To validate the payment request using Secure Hash,
  Merchant needs to Enable the Secure Hash Validation option in the
  merchant Backend under Account->Settings: Request Preference.
- Code implementation has to be done and an additional parameter has to
  be included on our EBS integration (Payment) file along with other DR
  parameter values (Account ID, Mode, return_url etc.), while posting
  the data to EBS server (http://secure.ebs.in/pg/ma/sale/pay).
- If the below MD5 hash value of
  "Secret_key|Account_id|Amount|Reference_no|Return_url|Mode"
  mismatches.
- Variable Name passed for the Secure Hash is "secure_hash"

Comment: Yes i got my solution i miss `ebskey `